# The method nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement, Object, int, SessionImplementor) of type BlobUserType must override or implement a supertype method

Tags: eclipse, hibernate

i'm trying to run an imported open source but i'm getting this error after running :

```
The method nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement, Object, int, SessionImplementor) of type        
BlobUserType must override or implement a supertype method
```

here's the method i diidn't put anything on it because i don't really need it , but i have to averride it .

```
      @Override
protected void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement ps, Object value , int index ,      
    SessionImplementor si) throws SQLException{}
```

Here's the class code :

```
   package org.squashtest.csp.tm.internal.infrastructure.hibernate;

   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.InputStream;
   import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
   import java.sql.ResultSet;
   import java.sql.SQLException;
   import java.sql.Types;

   import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
   import org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.LobCreator;
   import org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.LobHandler;
   import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.AbstractLobType;
   import org.hibernate.engine.SessionImplementor;
   public class BlobUserType extends AbstractLobType {

@Override
public int[] sqlTypes() {
    return new int[] {Types.BLOB};
}

@Override
public Class<?> returnedClass() {
    return InputStream.class;
}

@Override
protected Object nullSafeGetInternal(ResultSet rs, String[] names,
        Object owner, LobHandler lobHandler) throws SQLException,
        IOException, HibernateException {
       return lobHandler.getBlobAsBinaryStream(rs, names[0]);

}

@Override
protected void nullSafeSetInternal(PreparedStatement ps, int index, Object   
    value, LobCreator lobCreator) throws SQLException,
        IOException, HibernateException {


      if (value != null) {
          lobCreator.setBlobAsBinaryStream(ps, index, (InputStream) value, 
         -1);


     }
      else {
            lobCreator.setBlobAsBytes(ps, index, null);
      }


}




   }
```

Answer (score 3):

This method is written against different version of Hibernate than what you are using. As you see, UserType in [Hibernate 3.5](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/usertype/UserType.html#nullSafeSet%28java.sql.PreparedStatement,%20java.lang.Object,%20int%29) for example does have following:

```
void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st,
                 Object value,
                 int index) throws HibernateException, SQLException
```

[Hibernate 4.1](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/usertype/UserType.html#nullSafeSet%28java.sql.PreparedStatement,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionImplementor%29) on the other hand does have such a UserType class where method signature matches to your method:

```
void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st,
                 Object value,
                 int index,
                 SessionImplementor session)
                 throws HibernateException, SQLException
```

Comment: thank you but i tried to add an override of :void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st,
                 Object value,
                 int index) throws HibernateException, SQLException                                                            but it didn't work i added the code to my post you can check it if you want.  many thanks bro

Comment: And what happened? org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.AbstractLobType implements  org.hibernate.usertype.UserType. As a consequence Hibernate and Spring versions must be compatible, additionally org.squashtest.csp.tm.internal.infrastructure.hibernate.BlobUserType should agreed with contracts set by those two because it extends AbstractLobType.

Comment: i added a new jar   <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-search</artifactId>
   <version>4.2.0.Beta1</version>
  </dependency>
i think this is the source of the problem i'll chansge the version to 3.XX